# ESS[SAS] Submit region not working as expected -- each submission starts a new session

Tags: emacs, sas, ess

Specs: SAS 9.3, GNU emacs 23.4.1 (2012-06-05), and what I think is kind of an old version of ESS (sometime in 2001 maybe?). Unix -- I think SunOS 5.10.

I'm a fairly new emacs user and a very new user of ESS[SAS]. I have noticed that code which works when submitted as an entire file will not work when I submit it region by region. Here is an example:

```
libname mylib "/.";

data temp; set mylib.temp; run;
```

Assume that I have a directory as specified in libname and there is a SAS dataset called temp in it -- my code works properly when I submit the whole thing, but if I run just the first line and then the second, it tells me that "mylib" is not defined.

Based on the behavior of the log files -- the second submission creates a log file that overwrites the first -- I think what is going on is that it's starting a new SAS session with each submission. Why might it be doing this? (ESS does not do that with R code -- I can run a snippet to define a variable and then that variable stays defined.) I find I make fewer programming errors if I test things incrementally rather than running all my code in batch mode, and the GUI for SAS in unix leaves something to be desired, so I would really like to find a fix to this.

The only other clue I have is a pair of warnings I get on every submission:

```
NOTE: Unable to open SASUSER.REGSTRY. WORK.REGSTRY will be opened 
 instead.
NOTE: All registry changes will be lost at the end of the session.

WARNING: Unable to copy SASUSER registry to WORK registry. Because of 
 this,you will not see registry customizations during this session.
NOTE: Unable to open SASUSER.PROFILE. WORK.PROFILE will be opened 
 instead.
NOTE: All profile changes will be lost at the end of the session.
```

I googled those warnings separately and found they're commonly associated with a corrupt profile, but unfortunately the recommended fix did not fix anything (after deleting the iffy profile, it just restored itself and the error persisted). I am not sure whether this is related or not.

I realize this question might be out of scope for stackoverflow; if it is, a redirect to a more appropriate forum would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know enough to completely answer your question.  That said, I suspect it does start a new session every time you submit code.  There may be a way of working around this; if you have SAS/CONNECT licensed, for example, you may be able to have the server start a SAS/CONNECT session with itself.  SAS/CONNECT sessions are persistent (ie, they keep the libnames open) and allow you to remotely submit code iteratively like you suggest.

Comment: You also might have a better solution if you are running a GUI OS (like Windows) and connecting to Unix through telnet/etc; you could use Enterprise Guide; it's able to be installed on your desktop freely and then connects to the server.  It keeps its connection persistently open, and is a much better editor than using the Unix editor in my opinion (though it has a few drawbacks, and a lot of people would disagree with me on the quality of the editor).  This is largely the way SAS intends you to connect to its product nowadays.

Comment: Delete **~/sasuser.v94** and restart your session. After that you will be able to save your settings into registry.